# Unable to load caret package in R on R 3.1.0 on OSX 10.9

Tags: r, macos

I installed the R caret package using install.packages command and did library(caret). I am recieving the following error

```
>library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’
```

I searched other posts and also installed OSX tcltk package from http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ but it still does not seem to work. I also installed tcltk2 package from R but still does not work.. Kindly help

Comment: How did you install R and the packages? Did you use the Mavericks binaries from CRAN or did you install from source?

Comment: I used straight forward `install.packages `

Comment: caret do not depends on tcltk, so I think that something else causing this. What `traceback()` says? Does `library(tcltk)` works?

Answer (score 2):

I have met the same problem with the same error message but unfortunately, just reinstalling R1.3 didn't solve the problem for me.

To solve it, I had to install X-Quartz as explained [here](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/installation-notes.html) in the "Mac OS X Trouble-shooting" section and the problems related to tcltk.

Answer (score 1):

Do this and it will resolve the problem

```
install.packages("quantreg")
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of R are you using? Do you use Mavericks? You may need to update to a version which includes Mavericks updates.

http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: I am using R 3.1 on OSX Mavericks.. This problem does not seem to oocur on my macbook air which is also  running mavericks. Anyway will reinstall R and check

Comment: There are a few versions of R3.1, one is specific to Mavericks.

Comment: I had downloaded the Mavericks version. Anyways I deleted and re-installed R3.1 again on my system. I seems to work fine now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Reinstalling Quartz solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me.

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = T)
```

Once that is done, run

```
install.packages("pbkrtest", dependencies = T)
```